# Unity grid based movement collision problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I have been trying to make a collision system with grid based movement for a dungeon crawler. The collision works well enough as long as the player does not turn. When the player turns which is a 90 degree turn the collision system does not turn along with the player. This in turn lets the player walk through walls after turning.
Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool smoothTransition = true;
    public float transitionSpeed = 5f;
    public float transitionRotationSpeed = 500f;
    public float rayLength = 1f;

    Vector3 targetGridPos;
    Vector3 prevTargetGridPos;
    Vector3 targetRotation;

    float rayOffsetX = 0.7f;
    float rayOffsetY = 0.7f;
    float rayOffsetZ = 0.7f;


    Vector3 xOffset;
    Vector3 yOffset;
    Vector3 zOffset;
    Vector3 zAxisOriginA;
    Vector3 zAxisOriginB;
    Vector3 xAxisOriginA;
    Vector3 xAxisOriginB;

    private void Start()
    {
        targetGridPos = Vector3Int.RoundToInt(transform.position);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        yOffset = transform.position + Vector3.up * rayOffsetY;
        zOffset = Vector3.forward * rayOffsetZ;
        xOffset = Vector3.right * rayOffsetX;

        zAxisOriginA = yOffset + xOffset;
        zAxisOriginB = yOffset - xOffset;

        xAxisOriginA = yOffset + zOffset;
        xAxisOriginB = yOffset - zOffset;

    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MovePlayer();
    }



    void MovePlayer()
    {
        if (true)
        {
            prevTargetGridPos = targetGridPos;

            Vector3 targetPosition = targetGridPos;

            if (targetRotation.y > 270f && targetRotation.x < 361f) targetRotation.y = 0f;
            if (targetRotation.y < 0f) targetRotation.y = 270f;

            if (!smoothTransition)
            {
                transform.position = targetPosition;
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(targetRotation);
            }
            else
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime * transitionSpeed);
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(targetRotation), 
                    Time.deltaTime * transitionRotationSpeed);
            }
        }
    }



    public void RotateLeft()
    {
        if (AtRest) targetRotation -= Vector3.up * 90f;
    }
    public void RotateRight()
    {
        if (AtRest) targetRotation += Vector3.up * 90f;
    }
    public void MoveForward()
    {
        if (CanMove(Vector3.forward))
        {
            if (AtRest) targetGridPos += transform.forward;
        }
    }
    public void MoveBackward()
    {
        if (CanMove(Vector3.back))
        {
            if (AtRest) targetGridPos -= transform.forward;
        }
    }
    public void MoveLeft()
    {
        if (CanMove(Vector3.left))
        {
            if (AtRest) targetGridPos -= transform.right;
        }
    }
    public void MoveRight()
    {
        if (CanMove(Vector3.right))
        {
            if (AtRest) targetGridPos += transform.right;
        }
    }

    bool CanMove(Vector3 direction)
    {
        if (direction.z != 0)
        {
            if (Physics.Raycast(zAxisOriginA, direction, rayLength)) return false;
            if (Physics.Raycast(zAxisOriginB, direction, rayLength)) return false;
        }
        else if (direction.x != 0)
        {
            if (Physics.Raycast(xAxisOriginA, direction, rayLength)) return false;
            if (Physics.Raycast(xAxisOriginB, direction, rayLength)) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }



    bool AtRest
    {
        get {
            if((Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetGridPos) < 0.05f) && 
                (Vector3.Distance(transform.eulerAngles, targetRotation) < 0.05f))
                return true;
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use your transforms direction instead Vector's statics member (or the inverse, depend of what you want to do).

For example, `CanMove(Vector3.forward)` will be `CanMove(transfom.forward)`.

If you don't want relative direction, instead it's the `targetGridPos += transform.forward` who become `targetGridPos += Vector3.forward`

Comment: This will work, but as OP is doing grid based movement, I'd suggest using grid based collision instead of ray casting and using physic for that, although you'll have to refactor quite, you'll save yourself a lot of trouble later on